# How to trigger a Jenkins job on a different Jenkins server from a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

It's easy enough to call one Jenkins job from another Jenkins job if they're both jobs on the same Jenkins instance:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('call the say_hello job') {
         steps {
            build 'say_hello'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But how do we do this if the 'say_hello' target Jenkins job is **on a different Jenkins server** than the calling job?  (Not a different agent, I mean a completely different Jenkins instance managed by another group in my company.)

Right now we're doing it with calls to the Jenkins httpRequest plugin to trigger them, and then more httpRequest calls to poll the status of the remote job (so we can propagate their result states), but it feels a little kludgy and I was hoping there was a more robust way.

Comment: Hi, did you end up finding a way to do this? I am also trying to do the same and currently using the method provided in the answer below but I am looking for a more robust way.

Comment: Sorry, @KevinNiland I did not find a better answer at the time than "roll it yourself".  But I haven't worked with Jenkins in about 2 years, so hopefully there is a better solution out there for you now. If you find it, please come back and add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Enable the URL job trigger in destination job

2)Enable permission for “auto” in matix based security  add auto and set permission accordingly

3) you’ll need to use an API token. From the user list, click on the “configure” icon (the wrench and screw driver) next to the “auto” user.

4)do curl in stage from original job  http://auto:8702d1cb53a83f8748d9433ebca494fb@your-jenkins.com/job/JobName/build?token=iFBDOBhNhaxL4T9ass93HRXun2JF161Z

above url consist of api token , authentication token and user ( e.g.  auto )

Comment: Right, this is basically what we do now, except that we're using httpRequest to make the call instead of curl.  And this still doesn't manage steps like getting the result code of the completed job and propagating it to the calling job.